# WiFi won't work on another kernel version

Tags: wireless, kernel

I've got a problem about the detection of my WiFi card on other Linux kernel versions. When I run **ifconfig**, the card won't be listed in the network interfaces. The command line **sudo ifup ra0** shows the following:

```
ifup: failed to open statefile /run/network/ifstate: Permission denied
```

I currently use the "3.8.0-25-generic x86_64" kernel version in order for me to be able to connect to WiFi. All other kernel versions simply won't allow it.

I want to solve this issue before upgrading on 13.10 (I don't think upgrading will solve it at all, or will it?).

Here are all the informations needed:

Command lines results under working kernel: http://pastebin.com/mfFZZ6an

Command lines results under other kernels: http://pastebin.com/aVBSMZx3

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you compiled the driver rt5390sta from source code. It is compiled only for the kernel version that was running when you compiled. When a later kernel version is installed, typically by Update Manager, you must re-compile after rebooting into the later kernel.

```
cd Desktop/rt5390sta_files  <--or wherever you downloaded and extracted the driver
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt5390sta
```

I expect that upgrading to 13.10 will probably solve your issue.